# Windows Phone 8.1: executing code after disabling notifications in the device Settings interface

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-universal

I'm working in a Windows Phone 8.1/Windows 8.1 project that makes use of PushNotifications, running in a background task. This is working fine! The app receives the messages and the toasts are displayed to the user.

Once the app uses notifications, an entry is created in the "notifications + actions" interface, available in the Windows Phone device "Settings". In this interface, clicking in the app settings, the option "Show in action center" is marked as "On" by default. That's ok!

My question is: is there a way to execute some action/code from my app when the user change this Settings option? For example, if the user change the toggle from "On" to "Off", I would like to register, in the app's database, the date/time when the user changes this option.

Thank you for your help!

---

My scenario (extra explanation):

I'm working in a Windows 8.1 Universal app, that has an internal SQLite database. But, for now, my focus is in Windows Phone 8.1 platform. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3.

Imagine that you have a Windows Phone 8.1 device. In the main screen, swipe from right to left. Now, all installed apps are listed to you. Look for "Settings" and tap it. Inside the device Settings, in the "system" pivot, tap the "notification+actions" option. In this screen, below the checkbox "Show notifications in action center when my phone is locked", is listed all the installed apps that make use of some kind of notifications. In my case, one of them is the app that I'm working. Well, when you tap any app name from this list, another screen becomes available, containing the notifications settings of the selected app. The first option of this screen is an toggle switch, named "Show in action center". By default, it is setted as "On".

Here is my question: for example, if the user change the value of this toggle switch from "On" to "Off" (and vice-versa), I would like to register, in the SQLite database of my app , the date and time when user change this option. Is this possible?

OR THE OTHER WAY: if I implement a toggle switch inside my app, where the user can choose if he wants or not receive notifications, is there a way of, by code, to change the notification settings of the Windows Phone 8.1 device? For example: in my app, the user choose "Off" (he don't want to receive notifications). After, he accesses the "Settings/notification+actions" interface and, there, the "Show in action center" will be automatically set to "Off", once my app made this modification automatically. Is this possible?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This can't be UWP, Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1

Comment: Ok. Sorry. But about my question, any help?

Comment: If you can clarify your actual scenario and platform I am happy to take a look at it

Comment: Hello Anthony! Thank you for your attention! Please, sorry if my question wasn't clear. I described a "Step-by-step", trying to explain my scenario a little better. Please, if this explanation is still confusing, let me know. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please note that [tag:uwp] refers to Universal Windows Platform which is a common platform for all devices running Windows 10. For Windows 8.1 Universal app please use [tag:windows-8.1-universal] tag.

Comment: ZORRO, I already fix this tag 3 days ago.